# Package installation error in Yii2 framework?

Tags: yii2, phpmailer, phpspreadsheet, phpoffice

I have a requirement to use **PHPOffice/PhpSpreadsheet**, to install **PhpSpreadsheet** I followed [this](https://phpspreadsheet.readthedocs.io/en/develop/) link.

So I installed **PhpSpreadsheet** into my project using 'composer' by running the command

```
composer require phpoffice/phpspreadsheet
```

at command prompt while installing it said that

```
Using version dev-master for phpoffice/phpspreadsheet
```

and was installed successfully(FYI check Screenshot), after installing when I tried to login into my application, I am getting a different error as

```
Cannot redeclare PHPMailerAutoload()
```

(previously declared in" for emails I am using 'phpmailer' including the path as

```
require_once('../vendor/phpmailer/PHPMailerAutoload.php');
```

as my "PHPMailer" folder resides in 'vendor' folder of Yii2 framework.

By the way I am building my application on Yii2 framework and I am very new to Yii2 framework.

Can anyone please tell, how to fix this? Thanks.

[image]

Comment: Are you really developing a site without using git?

Answer (score 2):

You don't have to use require for packages installed via composer. [Yii autoload's feature](https://www.yiiframework.com/doc/guide/2.0/en/concept-autoloading) will take care for that. You just have to write the appropriate [use](http://php.net/manual/en/language.namespaces.importing.php) statements in your code. Actually, [the mailer is a component declared into the main app](https://www.yiiframework.com/doc/guide/2.0/en/tutorial-mailing), so you don't need the use statement at all

```
Yii::$app->mailer->compose('/my/mail_view', ['model' => $model])
                ->setFrom([Yii::$app->params['myMail'] => 'My Name'])
                ->setTo($model->email)
                ->setSubject('My subject')
                ->send();
```

Comment: I have included 'PHPMailer' folder manually in the 'vendor' of Yii2. So thats why I use 'require'. All this done before installing 'phpSpreadsheet' through composer.

Comment: There's no point to "including manually" modules to `vendor`. It won't be autoloaded until properly added to composer autoload classes! And you should never edit `vendor` manually!

Comment: You don't need the require. The mailer is a component which can be accesed via Yii:$app->mailer (please, see my updated answer).

Comment: As a rule of thumb, while your using Yii2, never require. Is you need to use something installed via composer, just write the use statement just before your controller's class declaration.

Comment: Sorry, I am a beginner to Yii framework, So, I don't know the usage correctly. I already built an application in corePHP and I am rebuilding that project on Yii2 framework. So, when I built using corePHP I have used 'phpMailer' for emails So, I should use 'phpMailer' only in Yii2 framework also. So, would you tell me how to use it?

Comment: @prasadchinthala you have an example in my answer. Also, please take a look at the Yii's autoload documentation to understand how it works (also linked on my answer).

Comment: I got your rule of thumb & understood 'Yii autoload's feature' too. I have fixed it by using 'require' only at both 'login' view & my model locations where I use 'phpmailer' like `require_once('../vendor/phpmailer/PHPMailerAutoload.php')` Thanks.

Comment: Again, see my answer, you have an example illustrating how to use phpmailer with yii. Also, I would advice you to read more about Yii's autoload.